# $scope.id vs $scope.watch("id", function(){})

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it might be very basic question but I couldn't find any satisfactory answer anywhere.

I want to watch $location.path() in my controller and update id accordingly. my code looks like this.

```
$scope.activeListId  = $location.path().slice(1);
```

it doesn't work and update activeListId but instead of binding direct attribute if i use $watch it works seamlessly

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
      return $location.path();
    }, function(value) {
        $scope.activeListId = value.slice(1);        
})
```

can someone explain what is the difference in above two? in my understanding they both are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is just an assignment at the point in time. You would have to watch for changes to update `activityListId`. Change tracking happens only for elements defined over the scope using watches.

These watches can take an expression bound to scope or a function that returns a value. When angular run a digest cycle ( a basic dirty checking cycle where Angular compare the current values being watched with their old value) it evaluates your function `$location.path()` for changes. If it finds any changes  it triggers the watch, where you set the `activeListId`.

When expressions are used in view, Angular internally sets up watch on these expressions.

You can learn more about the digest cycle [here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).